# Porting C++ struct to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, struct

First, let me show you the struct:

```
struct HPOLY
{
   HPOLY() : m_nWorldIndex(0xFFFFFFFF), m_nPolyIndex(0xFFFFFFFF) {}
   HPOLY(__int32 nWorldIndex, __int32 nPolyIndex) : m_nWorldIndex(nWorldIndex), m_nPolyIndex(nPolyIndex) {}
   HPOLY(const HPOLY& hPoly) : m_nWorldIndex(hPoly.m_nWorldIndex), m_nPolyIndex(hPoly.m_nPolyIndex) {}

   HPOLY &operator=(const HPOLY &hOther)
   {
      m_nWorldIndex = hOther.m_nWorldIndex;
      m_nPolyIndex = hOther.m_nPolyIndex;
      return *this;
   }

   bool operator==(const HPOLY &hOther) const
   {
      return (m_nWorldIndex == hOther.m_nWorldIndex) && (m_nPolyIndex == hOther.m_nPolyIndex);
   }
   bool operator!=(const HPOLY &hOther) const
   {
      return (m_nWorldIndex != hOther.m_nWorldIndex) || (m_nPolyIndex != hOther.m_nPolyIndex);
   }
   __int32 m_nPolyIndex, m_nWorldIndex;
};
```

There are some things I don't understand.

What does the repetition of HPOLY inside the struct mean? And how to transcript structs to delphi code?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suggest you might need to read some introductory books on C++...

Comment: Are you wanting to pass one of these structs across a boundary between a Delphi module and a C++ module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The repetition of HPOLY inside the struct are definitions of *constructors* for that type. In Delphi, the copy constructor (the third one in the C++, which constructs an instance of this type based on another instance of the same type) not necessary in Delphi. The two-argument constructor lets you specify initial values for the two fields. The default, zero-argument constructor sets the fields' values to -1, but Delphi doesn't allow such a constructor on records.

The next section in that struct is the assignment operator. Delphi provides that for records automatically. Next are comparison operators that compare the type for equality and inequality. The compiler will invoke them when you use the `=` and `<>` operators on `HPoly` values.

```
type
  HPoly = record
    m_nPolyIndex, m_nWorldIndex: Integer;
    constructor Create(nWorldIndex, nPolyIndex: Integer);
    class operator Equal(const a: HPoly; const b: HPoly): Boolean;
    class operator NotEqual(const a: HPoly; const b: HPoly): Boolean;
  end;

constructor HPoly.Create(nWorldIndex, nPolyIndex: Integer);
begin
  m_nPolyIndex := nPolyIndex;
  m_nWorldIndex := nWorldIndex;
end;

class operator HPoly.Equal(const a, b: HPoly): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (a.m_nPolyIndex = b.m_nPolyIndex)
        and (a.m_nWorldIndex = b.m_nWorldIndex);
end;

class operator HPoly.NotEqual(const a, b: HPoly): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (a.m_nPolyIndex <> b.m_nPolyIndex)
         or (a.m_nWorldIndex <> b.m_nWorldIndex);
end;
```

Comment: It's quite a time since I last wrote C++ but IIRC both the copy constructor and the assignment operator are superfluous in the original C++ code. The compiler generated defaults should suffice.

Answer (score 4):

`HPOLY` is an struct with only two 32 bit integer fields: `m_nPolyIndex` and `m_nWorldIndex`.

The first three lines are called contructors: code that gets executed whenever a new `HPOLY` instance is created. Then, writing the variable names after the colon means initializing the variable content.

For example, creating an empty HPOLY:

```
HPOLY x;
```

The first empty constructor is called on x. The value of `x.m_nWorldIndex` is 0xFFFFFFFF, and the value of `x.m_nPolyIndex` is 0xFFFFFFFF.

The other two constructors are manually initializing the two fields values:

```
XPOLY y( 1, 2 );

XPOLY z( y );
```

The value of `y.m_nWorldIndex` is 1, and the value of `y.m_nPolyIndex` is 2.

The value of `z.m_nWorldIndex` is `y.m_nWorldIndex`, and the value of `z.m_nPolyIndex` is `y.m_nPolyIndex`.

On Delphi the `TPOLY` struct can be translated to the following record:

```
TPOLY = Record
  m_nWorldIndex : Integer;
  m_nPolyIndex : Integer;
end;
```

Comment: +1 for your effort and for the proof of huch more readable Delphi code really is :)

Comment: @Smasher, part of the reason the Delphi code looks more readable is that it doesn't do as much as the original C++ code. Only the copy constructor and assignment operator are implicit in Delphi. Vz0's code omits the default constructor, which is not even allowed in Delphi, and it also omits the two-argument constructor and the comparison operators.

Comment: @Smasher I'm sure someone who was fluent in C++ would take a different view. What's readable to you may not be readable to others.

Comment: You are both right of course. I was not too serious about this (as indicated by the smiley)